# I cannot access to Pentaho server from remote PC

Tags: pentaho, web-access

From the server I can write in my browser: `http://172.24.XX.XX:8080/pentaho/Home` or with localhost and both work. But from any other computer I have not access (Web page not available), however, I ping from the PC to server `IP (172.24.XX.XX)` and I receive an answer.

Do you have any sugestions on where to find a log error at the server?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what server do you use?

Comment: A normal PC, windows 7 Enterprise, 64 bits

Comment: no, I meant do you use wamp, xampp, or other server?

Answer (score 0):

If `biserver-ce\tomcat\conf\server.xml` and 
`biserver-ce\tomcat\webapps\pentaho\WEB-INF\web.xml`are configured correctly, then it most likely be a windows firewall issue. Set a new inbound rule for Pentaho's port under Control Panel -> Windows Firewall -> Advanced Settings. Settings depend on your preference, just make sure you use the appropriate port. If you use Pentaho 4.8 and below, you may also wish to add a rule for the Admin Console.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had have to give access to java in the firewall